# Is there a way to merge two OutputStreams?

Tags: haskell, stream

[`OutputStream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams-1.5.1.0/docs/System-IO-Streams.html#t:OutputStream) is an abstraction that [looks like a contravariant functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams-1.5.1.0/docs/System-IO-Streams-Combinators.html#v:contramap) — one way to think of it is as of a continuation. Particularly, unlike its counterpart `InputStream`, it is not a container — it cannot give you any actual values.

[It has been shown previously how to split an `InputStream`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307729/is-there-a-way-to-split-an-inputstream) I would like to have it the other way around — to merge the `OutputStream`. That is, I require a function like this:

```
contrafork :: OutputStream a → OutputStream b → IO (OutputStream (a, b))
contrafork = …
```

One way to think of it is as of `instance Applicative OutputStream`.

#### So far my attempts go this far:

```
contrafork :: OutputStream a → OutputStream b → IO (OutputStream (a, b), Async ( ))
contrafork ω₁ ω₂ = do
  buffer ← newEmptyMVar
  ω ← ω₁ & contramapM (\ (x, y) → (putMVar buffer . Just $ y) >> return x) >>= atEndOfOutput (putMVar buffer Nothing)
  α ← makeInputStream (takeMVar buffer)
  token ← async $ connect α ω₂
  return (ω, token)
```

[`connect` is a loop under the hood](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams-1.5.1.0/docs/src/System.IO.Streams.Internal.html#connect) — this is where action happens. I have to make it asynchronous to avoid a *«thread blocked indefinitely»* situation, and then I have to pass a token outside that the consumer should wait on to ensure that both streams execute completely. Waiting in the wrong place can still result in thread lockdown. All in all, this solution leaves a better one to be desired.

#### What can be done?

This is a runner I use to see if my `contrafork` works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --resolver=lts-14 script
--package io-streams
--package bytestring
--package ansi-terminal
--package async
--ghc-options -Wall
-}

{-# language UnicodeSyntax #-}
{-# language OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# language BlockArguments #-}

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Exception
import Data.Function
import System.Console.ANSI
import System.IO.Streams hiding (map)
import qualified System.IO.Streams as Streams
import qualified System.IO.Streams.ByteString as ByteString

main :: IO ( )
main = do
  α ← "1\n2\n3\n" & fromByteString >>= ByteString.lines
  consoleWriteLock ← newMVar ( )
  [ω₁, ω₂] ← traverse (makeOutputStream . logMaybeLineWithColour consoleWriteLock) [Red, Blue]
  (ω², token) ← contrafork ω₁ ω₂
  α² ← Streams.map (\ x → (x, x)) α
  connect α² ω²
  wait token

  where
    logMaybeLineWithColour lock colour = maybe (return ( )) \ line → do
      ( ) ← takeMVar lock
      withSGRs [SetColor Foreground Vivid colour] $ print $ "Output line: " <> line
      putMVar lock ( )

contrafork :: OutputStream a → OutputStream b → IO (OutputStream (a, b), Async ( ))
contrafork ω₁ ω₂ = do
  buffer ← newEmptyMVar
  ω ← ω₁ & contramapM (\ (x, y) → (putMVar buffer . Just $ y) >> return x) >>= atEndOfOutput (putMVar buffer Nothing)
  α ← makeInputStream (takeMVar buffer)
  token ← async $ connect α ω₂
  return (ω, token)

withSGRs :: [SGR] → IO a → IO a
withSGRs sgrs action = bracket open close \ _ → action
  where
    open = setSGR sgrs
    close _ = setSGR [Reset]
```

If you make it executable and run in a console, you should see some interleaved red and blue lines.

Comment: There seems to be an extra requirement that the combined output stream doesn't block, is that right? Otherwise there's a pretty straightforward definition of `(Maybe a -> IO ()) -> (Maybe b -> IO ()) -> Maybe (a, b) -> IO ()` without any concurrency.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia  Not really. I am not sure what you mean by a stream not blocking. The solution that you outline would totally work. I came up with it too just about now. At first I did not realize that one can unpack an output stream to a simple function. You can write it up and get some points if you would like!

Comment: @Li-yaoXia, by the way, while we are at it — would it be correct to call this an instantiation of a monoidal functor in the Kleisli category of IO?

Comment: Cool. By "not blocking", I was referring to the issue that the `IO ()` actions from the two streams (that you run for each element `a` or `b`) could theoretically take arbitrarily long time, but by using concurrency you can produce an `OutputStream` whose `IO ()`  action returns in constant time, letting the actual work take place in the background. Yes, `OutputStream` and `contrafork` together form an example of a monoidal functor, but only in the Hask category. I don't think you get the expected commutative diagrams in Kleisli IO.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia  Can you explain this? `contrafork` is necessarily monadic, so I suppose it cannot be a monoidal functor in Hask.

Comment: I extended my answer to answer your category theory question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OutputStream a` is defined as `Maybe a -> IO ()`, so two streams can be merged as follows:

```hs
-- Let the types guide you.
merge_ :: (Maybe a -> IO ()) -> (Maybe b -> IO ()) -> (Maybe (a, b) -> IO ())
merge_ eatA eatB Nothing = eatA Nothing >> eatB Nothing
merge_ eatA eatB (Just (a, b)) = eatA (Just a) >> eatB (Just b)

-- Use `writeTo` and `makeOutputStream` to convert between `OutputStream a` and its underlying representation `Maybe a -> IO ()`.
merge :: OutputStream a -> OutputStream b -> OutputStream (a, b)
merge streamA streamB = makeOutputStream (merge_ (writeTo streamA) (writeTo streamB))
```

---

### Sidetrack

This appendix assumes some familiarity with category theory.

There was another question in the comments:

> would it be correct to call this an instantiation of a monoidal functor in the Kleisli category of IO?

`OutputStream` and `merge` together form a monoidal functor, but not in `Kleisli IO`.

A monoidal functor is defined between monoidal categories, so first we must spell out those categories. A *monoidal category* is a *category* with a *tensor product*. In the rest of this post we will refer to a monoidal category as "_ with _"; in practice, the tensor product ("with _") is often left implicit if it can be inferred from the context or after it's been said at least once.

The obvious candidate here for a monoidal category is `Kleisli IO` with `(,)`, but that is not a monoidal category: `(,)` is not even a bifunctor (when `Kleisli IO` is the relevant category), which would be necessary for it to be a tensor product. When you try to satisfy the definition of a bifunctor, you run into the problem that there is no function with the following signature that satisfies the composition law:

```hs
bimap :: (a -> IO c) -> (b -> IO d) -> ((a, b) -> IO (c, d))

-- Identity law (OK):
--     bimap pure pure = pure

-- Composition law (BROKEN):
--     bimap f1 g1 >=> bimap f2 g2 = bimap (f1 >=> f2) (g1 >=> g2)
```

The monoidal category you do have is the category of *functions*, with *cartesian products* (i.e., tuples) as the tensor product, hereafter denoted "`(->)` with `(,)`". And it happens that `OutputStream` with `merge` is a monoidal functor between the monoidal category `(->)` and its opposite.

The only way to confrm that is to walk through the definitions by yourself. Here's a rough list of all the things you have to check, which implicitly involves defining many functions and proving that they satisfy various laws, so each item hides a nontrivial amount of content if you're new to the concepts:

- `(->)` is a *category*.
- `(->)` with `(,)` is a *monoidal category*.
- We can take the *opposite* of a monoidal category, which is another monoidal category; here that gives us `(<-)` with `(,)`.
- `OutputStream` is a *functor* between the categories `(->)` and its opposite `(<-)`.
- `(OutputStream _, OutputStream _)` and `OutputStream (_, _)` are (bi)*functors*, where the domain is the product category `(->) x (->)` and the codomain is `(<-)`. (They are two ways of composing the bifunctor `(,)` with the functor `OutputStream`, so this comes for free if you accept that you can compose functors, but it's important to be able to spell them out to follow the other points below).
- `merge` (or more technically, `uncurry merge`) is a *natural transformation* between `(OutputStream _, OutputStream _)` and `OutputStream (_, _)`.
- `merge` satisfies some additional *coherence laws* (involving the monoidal categorical structure of `(->)` with `(,)`): `OutputStream` with `merge` is a *monoidal functor* between `(->)` (with `(,)`) and its opposite `(<-)` (with `(,)`).

Comment: Cute! [See also this pull request I just made.](https://github.com/snapframework/io-streams/pull/70)